# Which font Jetbrains uses in the screenshots of their products?

Tags: fonts, jetbrains-ide

Which is the font used for the source code in the screenshots of Jetbrains' IDEs shown in their [website](https://www.jetbrains.com)?

For instance, the one in this [image](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/img/screenshots/simpleLook@2x.jpg):

[image: pycharm screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Menlo, the standard code font on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it's either Monospaced (which is  usually default) or [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) - the one that supports font ligatures.